# I get a testing error on Typescript with React when trying to test if navbar goes to the links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, testing

I'm testing my navbar that I've created for my project in Typescript (using React) that I've built with Vite. I've successfully tested the "buttons" of the navbar, meaning they are there, but now I'm trying to test going to one of the buttons--meaning changing pages--when clicking one of them. Eg. the navbar has three things you can click on--home which brings you to the home page, Favorites which brings you to the Favorites page, and also one for Location. What I'm trying to do is to get the text from the pages that get clicked on from the Navbar, but it can't find the texts. The components (Home, Favorites, Location):

```
export function Home() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>
}
```

```
export function Favorites() {
    return <h1>This is favorites</h1>
}
```

```
export function Location() {
    return <h1>This is the Location page</h1>
}
```

The navbar component:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./navbar.css";

// Creates and exports the NavBar to be used in the application
export function NavBar() {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar-container">
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/favorites">Favorites</Link>
      <Link to="/location">Location</Link>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

App.tsx:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import { NavBar } from './navbar'
import { Home } from './Home'
import { Favorites } from './Favorites'
import { Location } from './Location'

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
    <NavBar />
    <div>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
            <Route path="/favorites" element={<Favorites />}></Route>
            <Route path="/location" element={<Location />}></Route>
        </Routes>
    </div>
    
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Finally, the test file for the navbar (ignore the first two "it" tests and scroll down to "describe":

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { NavBar } from "../../navbar";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { it, expect } from "vitest";

it("NavBar renders without errors", () => {
    render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <NavBar />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  });
  
it("NavBar contains navigation links", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <NavBar />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
    expect(getByText("Home")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(getByText("Favorites")).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(getByText("Location")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

// DOESN'T WORK, HELP. Test and ensure that the links in the navbar are working
describe("NavBar", () => {
    it("navigates to Home when Home link is clicked", () => {
      render(
        <BrowserRouter>
          <NavBar />
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
      const homeLink = screen.getByText("Home");
      fireEvent.click(homeLink);
      expect(screen.getByText("Hello")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  
    it("navigates to Favorites when Favorites link is clicked", () => {
      render(
        <BrowserRouter>
          <NavBar />
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
      const favoritesLink = screen.getByText("Favorites");
      fireEvent.click(favoritesLink);
      expect(screen.getByText("This is favorites")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  
    it("navigates to Location when Location link is clicked", () => {
      render(
        <BrowserRouter>
          <NavBar />
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
      const locationLink = screen.getByText("Location");
      fireEvent.click(locationLink);
      expect(screen.getByText("This is the Location page")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use await on the `screen.getByText("Hello")` ?

For example:

```
it("navigates to Home when Home link is clicked", async () => {
      render(
        <BrowserRouter>
          <NavBar />
        </BrowserRouter>
      );
      const homeLink = screen.getByText("Home");
      fireEvent.click(homeLink);
      await screen.findByText("Hello");
      expect(screen.getByText("Hello")).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
```

Since there is a state change you have to wait for the new state first.

Comment: Yes. I did try using await, but it didn't work.

Comment: Then try to utilized `screen.debug()` to understand what has been rendered after you click the `homeLink`.
https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-debugging/#screendebug